# What are the possible causes of sometimes using incorrect word ordering when speaking?

Tags: language

A friend sometimes speaks with incorrect word ordering. However, he writes English at a professional level. How could this be? His vocabulary is fine, just the word ordering is weird sometimes when he speaks. I always understand his meaning. He seems to not know that he is using incorrect word ordering. He speaks very slowly. His reading and listening appear fine.

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean by "incorrect word ordering"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_disorder#Possible_signs_and_symptoms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed your own word ordering as well as your word decisions?

Better: *Sometimes, a friend says his words jumbled, seemingly out of place. Though I understand him, always, he seems to be unaware of how he speaks. As well, she speaks slowly.
Yet, this friend writes well. Also, he seems to listen well. What could cause his problem?*

Look up *Anosognosia* and *Aphasia*.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. If you collect 50 reputation you can comment to any question.

Comment: After a lot of googling, I conclude that guy probably has Aphasia.